# I want to move checkbox label to left

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a checkbox code which I want to move the label from the right to the left while maintaining it's design

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container" style="color:#000 !important;">Select All
      <input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all"  />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label><br>
```

The result I expect is that the label is aligned to the left of the checkbox. Please help, how do I get this done?

Comment: in ``` .container ``` you may try ```text-align:left``` or ```float:left``` (less ideal) but I do not see the whole picture so cannot gurantee success. But worth a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.container selector must to be display:inline-block,padding-left change it by padding-right

.checkmark  change left by right

the result is

```css
  .container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container" style="color:#000 !important;">Select All
  <input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all"  />
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label><br>
```